# How do I fix my movement error in this Javascript program so it doesn't break when I press two keys at the same time?

Tags: javascript

I am coding a box that moves with arrow keys. I want to program it so when I press a key on my keyboard, the intervals detect the key pressed and puts the number value into an array called KeyDown. The function keyPressed detects if the keyCode is already in the keyArray as to not call it again, and have the box zoom across the screen, but rather at a consistent pace. If the keyPressed function does not find a duplicate, then it adds it to the array to be run by intervals and moveMover to move the box. Afterwards, when the pressed key is lifted, that specific instance is spliced out from the whole array.

The programs works find when I press my left and arrow key. However when I press two keys at the same time, the program can't splice both keys and as a result, one is left running. The box then continually moves to the left or right. I've tried to use logic to try to find a solution, but I don't understand.

This is the box moving program in all html, with css tags and style ones.

```js
function getTheStyle(id, styleProperty) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue(styleProperty);

  return theCSSprop;
}

function keyPressed(e, keyArray) {
  //check if keyCode is already in the keyArray

  for (i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {
    if (keyArray[i] == e.keyCode) {
      return;
    }
  }

  keyArray.push(e.keyCode);
}

function keyLifted(e, keyArray) {
  //check for every instance of the keyCode and splice it out, theory one instance, go through key array and make sure there isnt a copy anywhere
  for (i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {
    if (keyArray[i] == e.keyCode) {
      keyArray.splice(i - 1, 1);
      console.log(keyArray);
    }
  }
}

function moveMover(mover, keyArray) {
  //loop through key array, if number 39, if finds left key getting pressed, then add 2
  for (var i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {
    if (keyArray[i] == 39) {
      //left
      mover.style.left = parseInt(getTheStyle(mover.id, "left")) + 2 + "px";
      console.log(keyArray);
    } else if (keyArray[i] == 37) {
      //right
      mover.style.left = parseInt(getTheStyle(mover.id, "left")) - 2 + "px";
      console.log(keyArray);
    }
  }
}

//-----------MAIN PROGRAM ----------------------

var MoverTimer; //timer for user controled element
var mover; //inner moving element
var keysDown = []; //all the currently depressed keys

window.onload = function() {
  mover = document.getElementById("mover");
  MoverTimer = setInterval(function() {
    moveMover(mover, keysDown);
  }, 5);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

#mover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 130px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Two Movers</title>
</head>

<body onkeydown="keyPressed(event,keysDown)" onkeyup="keyLifted(event,keysDown)">

  <div id="mover"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: You have only one box, four keys to play with, so a simple object will do the trick, holds all of the keys as properties and their values either the key is pressed at this moment or not, and update it by listening to `keydown` and `keyup` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in `keyLifted`. It should be splicing on `i`, not `i - 1`:

```
function keyLifted(e, keyArray) {
  //check for every instance of the keyCode and splice it out, theory one instance, go through key array and make sure there isnt a copy anywhere
  for (i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {
    if (keyArray[i] == e.keyCode) {
      keyArray.splice(i, 1);
      console.log(keyArray);
    }
  }
}
```